Need to resolve no-unused-vars in lint
Below is my code and I couldn't figure out why it is running into no-unused-vars error?
import React from "react";
import TaskItem from "./TaskItem";
import { Task } from "@/app/api/interfaces/interfaces";

interface TaskListProps {
  tasks: Task[];
  onTaskCompletion: (taskId: number) => void;
}

const TaskList: React.FC<TaskListProps> = ({ tasks, onTaskCompletion }) => {
    return (
        <ul>
            {tasks.map(task => (
                <TaskItem
                    key={task.task_id} // Using task_id as key
                    task={task}
                    onTaskCompletion={() => onTaskCompletion(task.task_id)} // Passing task_id to onTaskCompletion
                />
            ))}
        </ul>
    );
};

export default TaskList;


It is giving me 7:22  Error: 'taskId' is defined but never used.  no-unused-vars
I am using this component in
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import TaskList from './TaskList';
import { Task } from '@/app/api/interfaces/interfaces';

interface TaskSheetDetailProps {
  taskSheetId: number;
}

const TaskSheetDetail: React.FC<TaskSheetDetailProps> = ({ taskSheetId }) => {
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState<Task[]>([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchTasks = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get(`/api/task-sheets/${taskSheetId}`);
                setTasks(response.data.tasks);
            } catch (err) {
                setError('Failed to fetch tasks');
            } finally {
                setLoading(false);
            }
        };

        fetchTasks();
    }, [taskSheetId]);

    const handleTaskCompletion = (taskName: string) => {
        setTasks(prevTasks => 
            prevTasks.map(task => 
                task.task_name === taskName ? { ...task, completed: !task.completed } : task
            ).sort((a, b) => Number(a.completed) - Number(b.completed))
        );
    };

    if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>;
    if (error) return <div>{error}</div>;

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Tasks for Task Sheet {taskSheetId}</h1>
            <TaskList tasks={tasks} onTaskCompletion={handleTaskCompletion} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default TaskSheetDetail;


I suppose the handleTaskCompletion will use the taskName passed from the component when the checkbox is clicked.
As for eslint, this is my current configuration:
{
  "extends": "next/core-web-vitals",
  "rules": {
    "no-console": "warn", // Disallow the use of console.log and console.error
    "no-unused-vars": "error", // Disallow unused variables
    "indent": [
      "error",
      4
    ], // Enforce 2 spaces for indentation
    "semi": [
      "error",
      "always"
    ] // Require semicolons at the end of statements
  }
}


Seems like you haven't set it up for TypeScript correctly, but as you haven't shown how it's set up at all it's hard to be more specific.

Could you check the onTaskCompletion function? Are you using the taskId there?

Thank you for the suggestions. I just added more details to my original post.

Could you share your eslint configuration? I've created the same file locally with mocking imports and no warnings for me...

Thank you for pointing that out. I just added it to the post.
